# How can I get AWS CodeBuild's outputted zip extracted in ElasticBeanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I'm trying to get AWS CodePipeline working with S3 source, CodeBuild and Elastic Beanstalk (nodejs environment)

My problem lies between CodeBuild and Beanstalk.

I have CodeBuild outputting a zip file of the final nodeJS app via the artifacts. Here is my CodeBuild buildspec.yml

```
version: 0.1

phases:
  install:
    commands:
      - echo Installing Node Modules...
      - npm install -g mocha
      - npm install
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Performing Test
      - npm test
      - zip -r app-api.zip .
artifacts:
  files:
    - app-api.zip
```

When I manually run CodeBuild it successfully puts the zip into S3. When I run CodePipeline it puts the zip on each Elastic Beanstalk instance in /var/app/current as app-api.zip

What I would like is for it to extract app-api.zip as /var/app/current. Just like the manual deploy via the Elastic Beanstalk console interface.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, a quick explanation. CodePipeline sends whatever files you specified as artifacts to Elastic Beanstalk. In your case, you are sending `app-api.zip`

What you probably *want* to do instead, is to send all the files, but not wrap them in a ZIP.

Let's change your `buildspec.yml` to not create `app-api.zip` and instead, send the raw files to CodePipeline.

```
version: 0.1

phases:
  install:
    commands:
      - echo Installing Node Modules...
      - npm install -g mocha
      - npm install
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Performing Test
      - npm test
#     - zip -r app-api.zip . **<< Remove this line**
artifacts:
  files:
    - '**/*'
# Replace artifacts/files with the value shown above
```

Comment: If it's not zipped - you may face a problem of files occupying to much space, and it would prevent it to be passed to ElasticBeanstalk through the pipeline.

Comment: @Georgij This shouldn't be an issue, as the artifacts will be zipped in transit by CodePipeline behind the scenes anyway, [as described here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/welcome-introducing-artifacts.html). The example above shouldn't have any significant affect on the artifact size.

Comment: Yes, you’re actually right, I’ve found that a bit later after I wrote the comment.

Answer (score 0):

**2023 Update**

Sending a zipped artifact from CodeBuild to Beanstalk still seems to be very problematic. In my case, the deployment folder was zipped with `maven-antrun-plugin` plugin during install, not by `buildspec` like above, and this had worked fine when uploading to the EB console or CLI.

But when CodeBuild `buildspec` was pointed at the same zipped artifact, EB failed with error

`An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [CheckProcfileForJavaApplication]. Stop running the command. Error: there is no Procfile and no .jar file at root level of your source bundle`

That was not the case, as I could download/unzip the deployment folder and run the jar locally. It was identical to what I'd typically upload via the console.

I finally noticed in a slight difference in `eb-engine.log`.

`/opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/app_source_bundle: Zip archive data, at least v1.0 to extract` **Locally built and uploaded to console - Works**

`/opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/app_source_bundle: Zip archive data, at least v2.0 to extract` **Zipped at CodeBuild - Doesn't work**

The solution provided by @Unsigned still appears to be the solution, or best practice rather.